# Emacs: by mistake binded M-x to a different function

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

By mistake I have binded M-x ( used for doing all the operations ) to a newly defined function ? How do I unbind it ? Now Alt-x always executes my function :( I dont want to exit emacs and restart again, I have lot of buffers open, so is there a way out here ?

Comment: you can save all your open buffers and restore them when emacs is started: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command usually run is `execute-extended-command`, just rebind it.

To rebind it, you have several options:

1. Just make what you did before, but just use instead your own function above mentioned `execute-extended-command`. If you did it with M-x command, then you maybe dont know, but M-x is not only produced by `Alt-x`, but as there are keyboard  layouts that have no Alt (or Meta) key, you can use `Esc x` instead.
2. Rebind it with elisp command. To do this, change to the `*scratch*` buffer, enter
   `(global-set-key (kbd "M-x") 'execute-extended-command)` and execute it with `C-j`.
3. Maybe by using the menue (I usually dont use it, so I am not sure on this point)

Comment: Thanks, I was exactly looking for what Alt-x function is called: execute exented command. Now I know :) but I am able to evaluate with C-j, it does nothing, just prints "Esc-" in the mini buffer.

Comment: Finally I did by C-x C-e to evaluate the expression in the buffer, since I had killed the default *scratch* buffer, C-j did not work, but the former key combination works in any buffer for evaluating the expressions.

Answer (score 4):

You could invoke `M-:` (or `Alt-Shift-;`) to run `eval-expression`.  Then use `global-set-key` to reassign "M-x" to its default value (`execute-extended-command`).

If you're worried about having a lot of buffers open and losing your workspace, you can always enable the `desktop` extension, which will save and restore the state of your buffers and windows.

Comment: I could not run M-, it says unbinded key

Comment: That's for Alt+: - ie. colon, not comma.